# Theorem or equation self-named after the same person that published it?

Tags: terminology, scientists

In the history of science, has there ever been a theorem/equation/law that is named after a person and has been coined that name by the same person?

Example: let's say somebody named Trevor discovers an equation that solves a certain kind of problems. In some of his publications, Trevor starts referring to the equation as "Trevor's equation". The name sticks and nowadays it is called the Trevor's equation.

Has a similar situation ever taken place?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure this is a clear cut case but when Stigler published [Stigler's law of eponymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stigler%27s_law_of_eponymy) he named it so in the title of the paper. The law states that no law is named after its discoverer and he did not claim to have discovered it himself or it would have falsified itself.